# nut ups master and slave across different networks

Tags: ups, apcupsd, nut

I have set up a NUT master and slave and they work great when on the same LAN.

Does anyone know if it possible to set them up across different networks? I can't find any reference to this anywhere when searching online and no one has been able to help on the NUT mailing list or via IRC/forums etc.

I have two servers that need to be on different networks but are still sharing the same cabinet and UPS.

When trying to get them to connect via IP address in the normal way editing the /etc/nut config files I just get an error that "UPS@ipaddress is unavailable".

I've tried adding "allowfrom =" with the external ip added in uspd.users on the master, as well as turning off the firewalls and opening port 3493 etc but nothing I've tried has managed to connect.

Thanks for any help to get this to work.

Comment: Your issue seems to be with forwarding rules in your firewall. What are you using as a firewall and what have you done to configure your firewall.

Comment: Hi thanks. I ended up changing the server's router and IP which got it to work. So it could of been an ISP/provider blocking issue or something with the router but I can confirm it does now work as it should. Thanks for the help.